# Filter out maps from a list of maps based on values inside the map in Java groovy

Tags: java, list, groovy, maps

I have a list of maps, with 3 key/values like this:

```
[
  [name: name1, date: Sat Oct 01 00: 00: 00 CEST 2021, doc: doc1],
  [name: name2, date: Sun Oct 14 00: 00: 00 CEST 2021, doc: doc1],
  [name: name2, date: Sat Oct 23 00: 00: 00 CEST 2021, doc: doc2],
//[name: name2, date: Sat Oct 15 00: 00: 00 CEST 2021, doc: doc2],
  [name: name2, date: Sat Oct 04 00: 00: 00 CEST 2021, doc: doc3],
  [name: name2, date: Sat Oct 11 00: 00: 00 CEST 2021, doc: doc4],
  [name: name3, date: Sat Oct 20 00: 00: 00 CEST 2021, doc: doc1],
  [name: name3, date: Sat Oct 03 00: 00: 00 CEST 2021, doc: doc2],
]
```

I need to find the most recent date for any given combination of name and doc, so for example if i have two docs of the same type for any given name i need to filter out all but the one with the most recent date.

In this case, I need to filter out the commented out line as another map with the same kind of name and doc exist with more recent date.

How can I accomplish this using a list of maps in Java Groovy?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I've tried all kind of things, and I don't want this question to be too specific to my problem but more about Groovy's lists and maps.

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#min(groovy.lang.Closure)

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupBy` your list over the values of the keys you want to
group (e.g.  `name` and `doc`).  Then `collectMany` over the resulting
map: if there is only one item in the `value`, return it; otherwise
reverse `sort` the items by the values of your sort-key (e.g. `date`)
and return the `tail`.